# Laravel 6: Eager load relationships of returned models from query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am building a tag filter. So far, I have a query that returns products who's tags or artists have been given to the query. I had to break it out since the if statements for the tag and author filters were a mess. The query is working and giving me all the results that I explicitly ask for in my select. But I need to get it to eager load each of the results relationships.  I tried dropping a with('tags') into the mix, but it just assigns an empty collection. I am pretty sure I need the with('tags') method somewhere, I am not sure where. Or I could be entirely on the wrong track. I don't have to limit myself to just the tags relationship (a one-to-many relationship, so I can't include it in the query results).

Here is my snarl of a query, `$tags` and `$artists` are the lists of tags and artists.

```php
if (count($tags)) {
    $tagged_products = DB::table('product_tags')
    ->whereIn('product_tags.tag', $tags)
    ->groupBy('product_tags.product_uuid')
    ->select('product_tags.product_uuid')
    ->havingRaw('count(product_tags.tag) = '.count($tags));
} else {
    $tagged_products = DB::table('product_tags')
        ->select('product_tags.product_uuid');
}

if (count($artists)) {
    $artist_products = DB::table('profiles')
    ->whereIn('profiles.attribution', $artists)
    ->select('profiles.user_uuid');
} else {
    $artist_products = DB::table('products')->select('products.user_uuid');
}

$results = Product::with('tags')
    ->join('profiles', 'products.user_uuid', '=', 'profiles.user_uuid')
    ->whereIn('products.uuid', $tagged_products)->whereIn('products.user_uuid',
    $artist_products)->get();

$results->dd();
```

If I query a single Product record, I can get the values of the tags relationship just fine.

Here are models:

```php
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'cost', 'description', 'thumbnail'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    public $incrementing = FALSE;

    public function tags(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductTag', 'product_uuid', 'uuid');
    }

    public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'user_uuid', 'user_uuid');
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'attribution', 'links', 'description', 'user_uuid',
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_uuid';
    public $incrementing = FALSE;

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'user_uuid', 'user_uuid');
    }   
}

class ProductTag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_uuid', 'tag',
    ];

    //
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_uuid', 'uuid');
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide us model as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily query like this:

```
  $results = Product::with(['tags' => function($query) use($tags){
                 if (count($tags)) {
                     $query = $query->whereIn('product_tags.tag', $tags)
                              ->groupBy('product_tags.product_uuid')
                              ->select('product_tags.product_uuid')
                              ->havingRaw('count(product_tags.tag) = '.count($tags));
                 }
                 return $query;
             }, 'profiles' => function($query) use($artists){
                 if (count($artists)) {
                     $query = $query->whereIn('profiles.attribution', $artists)
                                    ->select('profiles.user_uuid');
                 }
                 return $query
             } ]);
```

And remember add 2 functions `tags` & `profiles`

Comment: So that query doesn't filter. It does give me the profile relationship, but it has an empty collection for the tags relationship.

I can run `App\Products::find('457bef4d-6baa-561a-878b-1c86912256fd')->tags` in tinker and it does give me that model's tags so the relationship is functional.